# Oracle Regular Expression to show string a string after a special character

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I am using regexp to get all the sub string after a special character ':' appear-

Given String-

> Reason for creating the box: Order done by me (100005 - Error Format:
>   Value ABC000001606 of EmpId is not valid)

Expected Output-

> Order done by me (100005 - Error Format:
>   Value ABC000001606 of EmpId is not valid)

I try this one but not working as required-

> SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Reason for creating the box: Order done by me
>   (100005 - Error Format: Value ABC000001606 of EmpId is not valid)',
>   ':[^ ])') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" FROM DUAL;

Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's two ways to do it.

This one uses REGEXP_SUBSTR, as you requested.

```
with c as (select 'Reason for creating the box: Order done by me (100005 - Error Format: Value ABC000001606 of EmpId is not valid)' str from dual)
SELECT substr(REGEXP_SUBSTR(c.str, ':[^)]+'),2) "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" FROM c;
```

This one uses substr+instr+length, which has much better performance if you have a large dataset.

```
with c as (select 'Reason for creating the box: Order done by me (100005 - Error Format: Value ABC000001606 of EmpId is not valid)' str from dual)
select substr(c.str, instr(c.str, ':')+1, length(c.str)-1)
from c;
```

Both of these have a WITH clause to make the example query more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kfinity